# modular arithmetic question

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

know  some rules for modular arithmetic  expressions, for example,

1. $A+B=C\implies ((A\bmod M) + (B\bmod M))\bmod M = C\bmod M$.

2.$A\times B=C\implies $((A\bmod M)\times (B\bmod M))\bmod M = C\bmod M$.

($A$, $B$, $C$, and $M$  are just constant arbitrary integers)

But I did not understand the following  one
$$A - B = C \implies ( (A\bmod M)-(B\bmod M)+kM)\bmod M = C\bmod M$$
for some value $k$.

I am interested because,  as I know, such methods are used in computing   hash values of  strings and  generally   related with string search methods. My question is, what  does $k$ do in this case? Can we use arbitrary value of $k$? or  how to calculate which  value of $k$ is  relevant for such calculation? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know the meaning of modular arithmetic? If so then you will know that when you do any addition/subtraction/multiplication you might not get an answer that lies in the range 0,1,2,..., M-1 so you might have to manipulate your answer by a multiple of M

Comment: so it means that k=n*M?where n is some number?

Comment: No, notice that $k$ only comes up in the context $kM$, so it's a multiplier of $M$, not a multiple of $M$.

Answer (score 1):

$M\equiv 0 \pmod{M}$, so $M$ acts like zero in this type of expression.
So your expression is demonstrating the modification
$$
A-B=C \rightarrow A-B+k*0 = C
$$
from which it should be clear that $k$ can be arbitrary.